# Should RecordSet object be nulified in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, visual-studio-2005, vb6-migration

I am converting old VB6 app to newer VB.NET application and see these 3 lines often after the upgrade:

```
rs.Close()
'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object rs may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
rs = Nothing
```

Where rs is of type RecordSet like so:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

Should the last

```
rs = Nothing
```

line still exists? Or

```
rs.Close()
```

is enough?

Comment: One of the things you should upgrade is ADODB to ADONET

Comment: Good note. Are you talking about this: https://github.com/AlexGascon/ADODBNET/blob/master/ADODBNET/ADODBNET.vb ? @Plutonix

Comment: @Vlad: no, this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/index and you should use the `Using`-statement for objects implementing `IDisposable` like `DbDataReader`

Comment: ADONET is part of the NET framework.  The Access and SQL Server DBProviders are built in (`System.Data` namespace).  IF you are using something else (MySQL, SQLite) They have their own providers but still use  some of the DB agnostic tools (Datatable etc) from `System.Data`

Comment: RecordSet is a COM object, the finalizer of its RCW needs to run to get it truly destroyed.  Setting it to null actually *delays* that since the object is referenced a bit longer than necessary.  Not that you'd ever notice, the jitter by itself already deletes that code in the Release build.  However, if rs would be a field in a class object that lives for a while then setting it to Nothing can speed it up.  What the warning is *really* trying to tell you is that the underlying COM object will live longer than before.  Bad in the kind of app where the GC doesn't run often enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With VB.Net, you pretty much never set objects to `Nothing`. That was common in the VB6 era, but with .Net it's no longer helpful, and can in rare situations be actively harmful. What you should do is use the `Finally` section of a Try/Catch/Finally block (or the `Using` block for a shorthand) to make sure objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface have their `Dispose()` function called in a timely way, and in the case of the old ADO objects the `Finally` block is the place to call `.Close()`. You especially want to do this for the ADO connection object.

In summary, the `rs = Nothing` line should not exist, but `rs.Close()` isn't enough by itself, either.

But that's really a side issue here. If you're converting to VB.Net, the best thing is to also convert from the original ADO to the more modern ADO.Net, which is more idiomatic for VB.Net. This means using `DataSet` and `DataReader` instead of RecordSet in the first place.

Finally, this is also a good time to review your queries and make sure they are using query parameters rather than string concatenation. Hopefully you were already doing this, but there is a *lot* of old and scary-vulnerable classic-ASP and vb6 code out there, and a .Net migration is a good time to plug those holes. Sql injection isn't something to fool around with.

Comment: It was not needed in the VB6 era either: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/

Comment: @DaveInCaz Better now?

Comment: Also... reading through the post, Explanation #4 mentions a bug in ADO that forced you to do this to be sure the RecordSet and Connection are cleaned up in the correct order. So at least in the context of the question, `rs = Nothing` was "needed" in the vb6 era.